# Anime about two children whose respective fathers are turned to stone in the intro by a sorceress

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw the series in the early to mid 90s. The fathers may have been tied to pillars in a throne room before being turned to stone by a sorceress, which was shown in the intro sequence. Throughout the series the children  (I think a blonde girl and a dark-haired boy) were pursued by the sorceress's henchmen.

The children were helped in at least one episode by a priest until the priest engaged in a shoot out with the henchmen to allow the children to board a steam train.

Edit: Many thanks to @ConMan who identified the series, which I watched as the English dub. My recollection was a little off. The antagonist was not a sorceress but the Empress Dowager of China and the petrification spell was carried out by her court magician.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In which country and language did you watch this? Did you see it on TV or VHS? If it was on TV, do you recall which channel you would've watched it on, or if you can't recall the exact one, then which channels you might've seen it on?

Comment: Also, if anyone correctly identifies the series you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might have been "The Twins of Destiny" (aka *Les Jumeaux du Bout du Monde*), a French animated series from 1991 that was dubbed into a few other languages, including English. Some of the matching details:

> a blonde girl and a dark-haired boy

The main characters are a blonde girl named Julie and a Chinese boy (with dark hair) called Jules.

> fathers may have been chained to pillars before being turned into stone by the sorceress

Jules and Julie's fathers are imprisoned by the show's villain, the Dowager Empress, chained to pillars, and turned to gold statues by her court magician. I'm pretty sure that at some point in the series the episodes did start with "the story so far" segments that would have mentioned this.

The one part that I can't confirm is about the priest helping them get on a train during a shoot-out. The plot summary on Wikipedia mentions a lot of men who help them at various points, including a pirate and a magician, but the closest match to a priest would be a monk.

You can see the English opening here, which does show them on a train:

Or the somewhat better quality French version: